# Sybase Adaptive Server Anywhere connection problems

Tags: configuration, sybase, connections

In my work, we have a software system based on Sybase Adaptive Server Anywhere version 6 installed on Windows Server 2008. The system works fine, but after a period of time from system start, problems start. This period of time is variable: maybe an hour, maybe a day; the maximum stability period was one week.

The problem is: the logged-in users stay connected, but newly opened PCs the system can't login and the ODBC data sources window appears with a message, "can't find the server".

This problem, til now and as far as I know, has only one solution: to reboot the SQL engine, or reboot the server. This is so terrible because all connected PCs will stop the system and this may be in the middle of payment operations and so on.

We called technical support of the system, they can do nothing except clearing the log as it reached 21 MB. They said there is a very large amount of data in the log. When he cleared the log, the system stayed stable for one week, but now it started stopping again.

Also they mentioned that it might be because of cache memory in parameter `-c150MB`. They tried 300 instead of 150 and 120 but no way. I tried to add the parameter `-ti1400` to stop automatic disconnecting after period of idle time. I expanded it to about 24 hours!

I also asked the system software company to install a newer version of Adaptive Server Anywhere, but they didn't reply to that.

What shall I do to solve this?

Comment: Can you post the command you use to start the database server as well as the contents of the data source? Also note that Adaptive Server Anywhere version 6 was released about 14 years ago. You might want to consider upgrading - version 12 is current.